# post data using form works, but fetch API's not working in my case

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am working on React Project, currently making a signup form. 
Posting Form Data using **Form** works fine. But when i use `onSubmit={handleSubmit}`and use fetch API's like `axios` or just `fetch`, it stuck at `axios.post(url,options)`. I actually need to `Post` Users data and if User already exist than need to print error message at client side.

**Register Component** 1:

```
<Form method='POST' action="http://localhost:5000/api/register">
            <Form.Group  controlId="validationCustom01">
              <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Full Name"
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback>Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            
            <Form.Group controlId="validationCustomUsername">
                 <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                <InputGroup >
                    <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        name="email"
                    />
                </InputGroup>
            </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="validationCustom04">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control 
                    type="password" 
                    placeholder="Password"
                    name="password" />
                </Form.Group>
        <Button type="submit" className='button bg-success' >Submit</Button>
    </Form>
```

**Server.js**

```
app.post('/api/register', async (req,res) => 
    {
        let {name,email,password} =req.body
         if(password.length >=8 )
         {
            let hashpassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,10);
            pool.query(`SELECT * FROM USERSDATA WHERE EMAIL= $1 `, [email],
                 (err,results) =>
                     {
                         if(err){
                             throw err;
                         };
                         if(results.rows.length == 0)
                         {
                             pool.query(`INSERT INTO USERSDATA (NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD) VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING id`,[name,email,hashpassword],
                             (err,results) => 
                             {
                                 if(err)
                                 {
                                     throw error;
                                 }
                                 res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
                             }
                              );
                         }
                         else{
                             res.status(400) 
//Here i want to send error as response and to process this error at frontend
                             res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/register")
                         }
                      }
                     );
         }
    });
```

i tried to handle the Form submit using `handleSubmit` and made different fetch post requests but got different type of error while playing with the code. One of technique i used is given.

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
 e.preventDefault()
const options = {
method: "POST",
body:JSON.stringify(data),
headers:{
'Content-Type':'application/json'}}

    const res = await axios.post('/api/register', options) 
// here (above) i got many errors while playing different techniques like different fetch API's

  }}
return(
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} > 
...
...
</Form>
)
```

Is there any other way i can access `server response message` in React Component? As this took my 8 hours and still is unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = axios.post('/api/register', options)
```

i think you are missed to use await before axios post call

add await to the post calll

```
const res = await axios.post('/api/register', options)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to transform this form into a react component?
The best way to do it is to control field into state after that you could sent it via `axios` in the click of your submit button

Something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, InputGroup, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

const getInitialState = () => ({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: ""
});

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(getInitialState());
  const handleSubmit = async (data) => {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
    return axios.post("/api/register", options);
  };

  const handleChange = (field) => (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [field]: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleSubmit(formData);
      }}
    >
      <Form.Group controlId="validationCustom01">
        <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Full Name"
          value={formData.name}
          onChange={handleChange("name")}
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group controlId="validationCustomUsername">
        <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
        <InputGroup>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange("email")}
          />
        </InputGroup>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="validationCustom04">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          name="password"
          value={formData.password}
          onChange={handleChange("password")}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button type="submit" className="button bg-success">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();   // preventing the page to be refreshed while submitting the FORM
    store()
});


const store = async(e)=> {

    let name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
    let email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    let age = document.querySelector("#age").value;
    let phone = document.querySelector("#phone").value;
    let pass = document.querySelector("#password").value;
    let address = document.querySelector("#Address").value;
    let country = document.querySelector("#country").value;
    let state = document.querySelector("#state").value;
    let pincode = document.querySelector("#pincode").value;

    // storing these values in a object
    let personOBJ = { // want to keep the key name and value name same then
        email,
        pass,
        name,
        address,
        country,
        state,
        pincode
    };
    
    let fetchData = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/users/register",{
        method : "POST",
        headers : {
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(personOBJ)
    })
    .then(result=>{
        result.json()
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```